# Android ICS : Failed to handle callback; interface not implemented, callback:android.view.View$PerformClick@40d80cc8

Tags: android, android-button

I am experiencing very weird behavior on ICS devices. I have a button in layout and click Listener as bellow .

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // To just demonstrate weird behavior, i am throwing run-time exception 
         throw new RuntimeException("testing weird behavior on ICS");

         //String s = null;   s.length(); You can try this , application does not crash.
        } 
    });
}
```

In normal conditions, this should crash application but surprisingly, i can see a crash in logcat as bellow but application does not crash. Rather i see

```
Failed to handle callback; interface not implemented, callback:android.view.View$PerformClick@40d80cc8
java.lang.RuntimeException: testing weird  behaviour
     at com.example.sampleproject.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:21)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea why I am experiencing this weird behavior, any help is appreciated.

As per @Jen suggestion , I tried  b.performClick(); , and application shows normal behavior but still same behavior in onClickListener   .

I filed bug here is link
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35517&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Does it react the same if you call `performClick()` using code. ICS posts a `Runnable` that executes the click -  letting the UI state update before running the click code - that could very well be an effect of that.

Comment: @Jens onPerform Click it crashes properly

Comment: Then its the fact that it's posting `Runnable`s to the `View`s `Handler` that's causing the change in behavior. Funky..

Comment: Seems like bug in platform ??

Comment: It's a discrepancy in error handling at least. Typically one shouldn't be throwing exceptions in `onClick` - but I can imagine that this would make it a bit harder to track down errors "in the wild" if no force closes are reported back on apps that do a lot of work in their click handlers.

Comment: +1 from me, as I've learnt more about the innards of the framework (have not dug deep into that code for the view) Has this been reported I wonder, or fixed in 4.0.4 source.

Comment: I checked our source tree and this error message "Failed to handle callback" does not appear anywhere. What phone/ROM are you using? This could be a change made by an OEM or ROM provider that catches exceptions thrown by messages.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly this behaviour on an HTC One X: a 'deliberate crash' button from a testing activity: Android 4.0.3, HTC Sense 4.0, software number 1.29.401.11, HTC SDK 4.12, HTC Extension HTCExtension_403_1_GA_7, build number 1.29.401.11 CL62864 release-keys

Comment: Uh, that's a RuntimeException deliberate crash btw.

Comment: I'm successfully crashing(!) by setting a flag and calling 'finish()' in the listener, and conditionally throwing my exception in onPause().

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking if button `b` is null? As the logcat states `java.lang.NullPointerException`, strange that you're experiencing the issue, what I have usually is this:

```
_btnFoo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFoo);
if (_btnFoo != null){
   _btnFoo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v){
         ....
      }
   });
}
```

Its the null pointer exception that sticks out like a sore thumb so something is not initialized there around that.

**Edit:** 
Since my answer was not sufficient enough, I thought of digging around the sources, taken from the ICS 4.0.3 repo, this is a section of the code found here, at lines 14103 in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java`

```
private final class PerformClick implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        performClick();
    }
}
```

The meat of the method is in this found at lines 3505 in the same source:

```
public boolean performClick() {
        sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);

        ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
        if (li != null && li.mOnClickListener != null) {
            playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            li.mOnClickListener.onClick(this);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

<s>My guess is that the `Runnable` within the `PerformClick` is glitchy since it appears to be cross-threading without any hint of `runOnUiThread` or similar safeguard.</s>

I'll stress that in the previous sentence - I'll put an open-ended question-mark and use it loosely in the sense of the word as in, not to be taken literally.

Jen's comment is proven to be correct as shown here, taken from lines 3010:

```
case R.styleable.View_onClick:
    if (context.isRestricted()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The android:onClick attribute cannot "
                + "be used within a restricted context");
    }

    final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
    if (handlerName != null) {
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            private Method mHandler;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mHandler == null) {
                    try {
                        mHandler = getContext().getClass().getMethod(handlerName,
                                View.class);
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        int id = getId();
                        String idText = id == NO_ID ? "" : " with id '"
                                + getContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                                    id) + "'";
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find a method " +
                                handlerName + "(View) in the activity "
                                + getContext().getClass() + " for onClick handler"
                                + " on view " + View.this.getClass() + idText, e);
                    }
                }

                try {
                    mHandler.invoke(getContext(), View.this);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute non "
                            + "public method of the activity", e);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute "
                            + "method of the activity", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    break;
```

At line 3452, the `setOnClickListener` method is where the call-back gets registered as shown:

```
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    if (!isClickable()) {
        setClickable(true);
    }
    getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
}
```

The answer to the OP's question is there's a bug in the framework as Jens succinctly put it *It's a discrepancy in error handling at least. Typically one shouldn't be throwing exceptions in `onClick` - but I can imagine that this would make it a bit harder to track down errors "in the wild" if no force closes are reported back on apps that do a lot of work in their click handlers.*

Comment: Updated stacktrace , I tried Run time exception as well as throwing NPE  also

Comment: Ho okie... guess my answer is not quite a help to you :) Another thing, why View.OnClickListener? See the parameter I used there...

Comment: Thanks biggest surprise is if you try b.perfomClick it crashes app but not in other case.

Comment: "*My guess is that the Runnable within the PerformClick is glitchy since it appears to be cross-threading without any hint of runOnUiThread or similar safeguard.*", this is incorrect - the runnable is posted to the `Handler` attached to the `View`, it runs on the UI-thread, just as any other UI-action - it's done like this to defer the code in the click handler until after the UI state has been updated, which makes the UI appear more responsive.

Comment: @Jens - thanks for the clarification as I was not quite sure myself :)